# Finding 3 specific byte values within a set number of bytes of each other

Tags: regex, notepad++

I extracted a large number of bytes from an ISO into Notepad++ and ended up with 131,076 characters worth of space-separated values.

I would like to find where there occur at least three specific values within a fixed number of bytes of each other.

As an example, I would like the values `11`, `12`, and `B4` to be highlighted if they are within 18 bytes (=53 characters) of each other, in this:

```
03 00 1F 06 01 15 12 10 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 
04 00 3B 06 02 25 02 11 00 03 06 00 00 85 65 88 00 00 
05 00 24 06 11 15 12 10 00 06 09 00 00 0C 7C 1A 00 00 
06 00 41 04 12 24 01 11 00 00 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 00 
07 00 26 03 11 15 12 01 00 00 00 00 00 B4 00 00 00 00 
08 00 0E 06 10 15 11 11 00 08 00 00 00 CB 7C 00 00 00 
09 00 0A 00 10 11 01 21 00 06 00 00 00 68 BD 00 00 00 
0A 00 5B 07 10 10 20 11 00 00 00 00 00 3D 00 00 00 00 
0B 00 40 00 12 24 01 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The required result is the following, where the square brackets indicate which values need to be highlighted:

```
03 00 1F 06 01 15 12 10 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 
04 00 3B 06 02 25 02 11 00 03 06 00 00 85 65 88 00 00 
05 00 24 06 11 15 12 10 00 06 09 00 00 0C 7C 1A 00 00 
06 00 41 04 12 24 01 11 00 00 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 00 
07 00 26 03[11]15[12]01 00 00 00 00 00[B4]00 00 00 00 
08 00 0E 06 10 15 11 11 00 08 00 00 00 CB 7C 00 00 00 
09 00 0A 00 10 11 01 21 00 06 00 00 00 68 BD 00 00 00 
0A 00 5B 07 10 10 20 11 00 00 00 00 00 3D 00 00 00 00 
0B 00 40 00 12 24 01 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Can this be done? (If not, is it possible to do so for only two values?)

Notes:

- The values can appear in any order.
- I don't want to clear the data around the values, just highlight them or make them stand out so that I can track and use the values to understand how a certain table works within an ISO.
- The above example contains line-feeds/carriage returns just for readability. The actual data doesn't contain any - all the values are space-separated only.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show what you want highlighted within those bytes.

Comment: Just 11, 12, B4 for this example to learn how to do it.

Comment: *@Luminaires* Welcome to Super User! Just to be clear before I tidy up your question: 1) Are you trying to highlight three or more specific values within a set distance from each other by using a regular expression search? 2) Can those values appear in any order? § PS For a user to get notified of a comment targeted at them, you need to "ping" them like I have done in this comment. See [How do comment @replies work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) for more info. Note that you can't just ping anyone in a comment, only the post author and every other user that has previously commented.

Comment: @robinCTS Yeah all of that is correct they can appear in any order really I'm just pretty bad at explaining things regretfully.

Comment: OK. I've polished the question and voted to reopen it. The short answer is - yes this can be done with a regular expression search, with the caveat that you can't just highlight the three values. Instead, you have to highlight the entire range starting at the first found value (`11` in your example) through to the last found value (`B4`). The regex is a bit long, but relatively simple. It can be extended to cater for more than three values, but it starts to get unwieldy for much more than three.

Comment: What happens when there are 2 consecutive numbers? There's not enough space for 2 brackets. Also, what about the bytes at the beginning of the line? Again, no space. @Luminaires